# How to filter Output Window to print only System.Diagnostics.Debug?

Tags: c#, debugging

I've been debugging using System.Diagnostics.Debug and my attention has to compete with other output information that I don't want to see

how do I filter only the messages I want?

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Debug("ZZZZZ"+realDebugMessage)`

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/09/the-output-window-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/